# show reverse dependencies with pip?

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

Is it possible to show the reverse dependencies with `pip`?

I want to know which package needs package `foo`. And which version of `foo` is needed by this package.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible for already installed packages using pip's python API. There is the `pip.get_installed_distributions` function, which can give you a list of all third party packages currently installed.

```
# rev_deps.py
import pip
import sys

def find_reverse_deps(package_name):
    return [
        pkg.project_name for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions()
        if package_name in {req.project_name for req in pkg.requires()}
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print find_reverse_deps(sys.argv[1])
```

This script will output the list of packages, that require a specified one:

```
$python rev_deps.py requests
```

Answer (score 17):

To update the answer to current (2019), when `pip.get_installed_distributions()` does not exist anymore, use `pkg_resources` (as mentioned in [a comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336323/show-reverse-dependencies-with-pip#comment80714434_26300187)):

```
import pkg_resources
import sys

def find_reverse_deps(package_name):
    return [
        pkg.project_name for pkg in pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
        if package_name in {req.project_name for req in pkg.requires()}
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_reverse_deps(sys.argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 14):

I found Alexander's answer perfect, except it's hard to copy/paste. Here is the same, ready to paste:

```
import pip
def rdeps(package_name):
    return [pkg.project_name
            for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions()
            if package_name in [requirement.project_name
                                for requirement in pkg.requires()]]

rdeps('some-package-name')
```

Comment: For the record, pip does not have a public API. This answer will be invalid by pip 10. Use `pkg_resources` from setuptools instead.

Comment: Ref for @AlexGrönholm's comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Answer (score 7):

One can use the `pipdeptree` package. To list reverse dependencies of an installed `cffi` package:

```
$ pipdeptree -p cffi -r
cffi==1.14.0
  - cryptography==2.9 [requires: cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3]
    - social-auth-core==3.3.3 [requires: cryptography>=1.4]
      - python-social-auth==0.3.6 [requires: social-auth-core]
      - social-auth-app-django==2.1.0 [requires: social-auth-core>=1.2.0]
```