# How to find reverse dependency on python package

Tags: python, dependencies, package, pip

I have one virtual environment, where `elasticsearch` python package was installed.

I want to find, which package has dependency on `elasticsearch` and did installation in virtual environment.

```
(.venv)root@test:~# pip freeze | grep elast
elasticsearch==1.4.0.dev0
```

I tried some solution from [show reverse dependencies with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336323/show-reverse-dependencies-with-pip) but its not worked

```
(.venv)root@test:~# python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 18 2014, 12:50:18)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
>>> package_name = 'elasticsearch'
>>> rev_dep = [pkg.project_name for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions() if package_name in [requirement.project_name for requirement in pkg.requires()]]
>>> rev_dep
[]
>>>
```

Path of module return virtual env path.

```
(.venv)root@test:~# python -c 'import elasticsearch; print elasticsearch.__path__'
['/opt/venvs/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch']
```

I have doubt that `elasticsearch` debian package might be installed this python package, but not sure.

```
(.venv)root@test:~# dpkg -l | grep elast
ii  elasticsearch                        1.2.0                           all          Open Source, Distributed, RESTful Search Engine
```

Comment: First, check where `elasticsearch` is installed (so you can know whether you're using the system package or not). Please provide the output of: `python -c 'import elasticsearch; print elasticsearch.__path__'`.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1.  find your site-packages directory for your virtualenv:

Note my shell prompt showing `venv38` and the egrep at the end.

`(venv38) myuser@foo$ python -m site | egrep venv38`

The site.py module has all sorts of interesting info, but we are only interested in the venv's site-package.

#### Output:

```
'/Users/myuser/kds2/py2/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
```

#### Step 2. look for dependencies in the `*dist-info/METADATA` files

change to the site-packages directory you found above.

I am looking for who is using `bleach` rather than `elasticsearch`

```
cd /Users/myuser/kds2/py2/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages

find . -name METADATA -exec grep -H -i bleach {} \; | grep Requires-Dist
```

Note:  although it's not necessary to worry about it here, characters like `-` or `_` in the package name may affect how the grep should be written.

#### output:

```
./readme_renderer-24.0.dist-info/METADATA:Requires-Dist: bleach (>=2.1.0)
```

So, the `readme_renderer` is what is pulling in this dependency.

Note using `find . -name METADATA -exec grep -H Requires-Dist {} \; | grep bleach` i.e. interchanging the grep sequence between Requires-Dist and your searched-for package doesn't work as well, as, in my case, it showed a lot of `bleach`s own dependencies.