# How to find a Python package's dependencies

Tags: python, pip

How can you programmatically get a Python package's list of dependencies?

The standard `setup.py` has these documented, but I can't find an easy way to access it *from* either Python or the command line.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
$ pip install somepackage --only-list-deps
kombu>=3.0.8
billiard>=3.3.0.13
boto>=2.26
```

or:

```
>>> import package_deps
>>> package = package_deps.find('somepackage')
>>> print package.dependencies
['kombu>=3.0.8', 'billiard>=3.3.0.13', 'boto>=2.26']
```

Note, I'm not talking about importing a package and finding all referenced modules. While this might find most of the dependent packages, it wouldn't be able to find the minimum version number required. That's only stored in the setup.py.

Comment: Quite a few answers here show pip being imported for use in programs. The [documentation for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id30) strongly advises against this usage of pip. Something to keep in mind in case any of these solutions are being used for anything important.

Answer (score 207):

In addition to the `pip show [package name]` command, there is `pipdeptree`.

Just do

```
$ pip install pipdeptree
```

then run

```
$ pipdeptree
```

and it will show you your dependencies in a tree form, e.g.,

```
flake8==2.5.0
  - mccabe [required: >=0.2.1,<0.4, installed: 0.3.1]
  - pep8 [required: !=1.6.0,>=1.5.7,!=1.6.1,!=1.6.2, installed: 1.5.7]
  - pyflakes [required: >=0.8.1,<1.1, installed: 1.0.0]
ipdb==0.8
  - ipython [required: >=0.10, installed: 1.1.0]
```

The project is located at https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree, where you will also find usage information.

Comment: `pipdeptree` show the dependencies of *all* *installed* packages, not only those of a given package. While you could filter its `--json` output, it still depends on the packages to be already installed.

Comment: True, but the answer is still useful when you want to get a hold of why packages were installed that are not in your `requirements.txt` :)

Comment: Plus you can use the [`-p` option](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree#usage) to only select a few packages whose dependencies you want to explore.

Comment: `pipdeptree` was super helpful when optimizing `requirements.txt`.

`$ pipdeptree | grep -P '^\w+'`  
This outputs only top level packages.  

More info [here](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree#using-pipdeptree-to-write-requirementstxt-file)

Comment: Do `python -m pipdeptree` if you are using virtual environment.

Comment: @DeepamGupta Just `pipdeptree` should work in a virtual environment too.

Comment: Yes, I retried now, and it worked, idk why it wasn't working when I tried before. And hence, I have to try `python -m pipdeptree`. Thanks btw.

Comment: @LeadDeveloper And if you already have `setuptools` installed, you can produce a complete requirements list with: `import pkg_resources as P, pprint; inst_pkgs = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in P.working_set]); pprint.pprint(inst_pkgs)`

Comment: For desired package only: pipdeptree -r -p package-name

Answer (score 119):

Try to use `show` command in `pip`, for example:

```
$ pip show tornado
---
Name: tornado
Version: 4.1
Location: *****
Requires: certifi, backports.ssl-match-hostname
```

**Update** (retrieve deps with specified version):

```
from pip._vendor import pkg_resources


_package_name = 'somepackage'
_package = pkg_resources.working_set.by_key[_package_name]

print([str(r) for r in _package.requires()])  # retrieve deps from setup.py
```

---

```
Output: ['kombu>=3.0.8', 
         'billiard>=3.3.0.13', 
         'boto>=2.26']
```

Comment: That tells you the version of the *package*, not its *dependencies*; they just get listed.

Comment: See `Requires` section

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show *"the minimum version number required"*, as the OP requires:

Comment: Somehow `$ pip3 show beautifulsoup4` shows empty `Requires: ` for me -- doesn't beautifulsoup4 depend on anything?

Comment: @xealits, I just tried installing `beautifulsoup4` in a virtualenv and it looks like it doesn't depend on anything.

Comment: @PythonJin, yep, apparently it uses only standard packages.. I just was a bit surprised with that. Well done, `beautifulsoup4`.

Answer (score 47):

Brief summary about the methods that are found and tested on the Windows machine:

1. Parse the json file of PyPI: `https://pypi.org/pypi/<package>/<version>/json` ([#7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50424967))
2. Check `/site-packages/<package-version>.dist-info/METADATA` ([#13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353494), pre-installation required)
3. `pip install --no-install <package>`: deprecated ([#11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148336))
4. `pip install --download <package>`: deprecated ([#12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632486))
5. `pip show <package>` ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751732), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319754), pre-installation required)
6. Write a script with `import pip` and `pip._vendor.pkg_resources`: deprecated ([#6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781516))
7. Write a script with `import pkg_resources` of `setuptools` package ([#4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938959), pre-installation required)
8. Check https://libraries.io/ ([#5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58991493))
9. Use `pipdeptree` package ([#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39488113), [#8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41816693), pre-installation required)
10. Use `Johnnydep` package ([#10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49472328)): Test hangs in many cases.
11. `conda info [package_name]`: deprecated ([#9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666077))
12. `conda search [package_name] --info`

    - Additional packages can be listed: `vc2015_runtime`, `python_abi`, `libflang`, and etc.
    - Note that this method can list different packages depending on the build and channel.
      e.g. `conda search "Django==3.2" --info -c conda-forge`

```
django 3.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
-----------------------
file name   : django-3.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
...
timestamp   : 2021-04-06 20:19:41 UTC
dependencies:
  - asgiref
  - psycopg2
  - python
  - pytz
  - sqlparse

django 3.2 pyhd8ed1ab_0
-----------------------
file name   : django-3.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
...
timestamp   : 2021-04-07 21:15:25 UTC
dependencies:
  - asgiref >=3.3.2,<4
  - python >=3.6
  - pytz
  - sqlparse >=0.2.2
```

One more thing to note is that each method can provide a different result.

For example, `requests/setup.py` [identifies](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/setup.py) `chardet`, `idna`, `urllib3`, and `certifi` are required. Moreover, extra packages `pyOpenSSL`, `cryptography`, `socks`, `PySocks`, `win-inet-pton` can be needed.

- Methods 1 and 2 agree with it.
- Method 8 just list all of them (pressing the explore dependencies button just hangs).
- Method 12 just list `chardet`, `idna`, `urllib3`, and `certifi`.
- Methods 5 and 7 does not list any dependency if `requests` is installed using `pip` in the Linux docker.
- Methods 5, 7, 9, and 10 list `chardet`, `idna`, `urllib3`, and `certifi` if `requests` is installed in the conda environment of the Windows machine.

Comment: Excellent post! So to summarize, the only options that are not deprecated, do not require pre-installation, and are reliable, are #1 (parse pypi.org json), #8 (libraries.io).

Comment: The libraries.io `Explore dependencies` button did work for me now. For example https://libraries.io/conda/pandas/2.0.3/tree returned results.

Answer (score 19):

The standard library offers `importlib.metadata.requires()` since version 3.8 and onwards:

```
In [1]: from importlib.metadata import requires

In [2]: requires('pytype')
Out[2]:
['attrs (>=21.2.0)',
 'importlab (>=0.6.1)',
 'libcst',
 'ninja (>=1.10.0.post2)',
 'pyyaml (>=3.11)',
 'six',
 'tabulate',
 'toml',
 'typed-ast (>=1.4.3)',
 'dataclasses ; python_version < "3.7"']
```

For older Python versions, there's the [`importlib-metadata`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) available. Related section in Python docs: [Distribution requirements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-requirements).

If you need to parse the strings returned by `requires()`, I strongly suggest to use `packaging` library since its [`packaging.requirements`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/requirements.html) module is a reference implementation of [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/). Example with a complex dependency specification string:

```
In [3]: from packaging.requirements import Requirement

In [4]: spec = 'requests [security,test] (>=2.21.0) ; implementation_name == "cpython"'

In [5]: r = Requirement(spec)

In [6]: r.name
Out[6]: 'requests'

In [7]: r.specifier
Out[7]: <SpecifierSet('>=2.21.0')>

In [8]: r.extras
Out[8]: {'security', 'test'}

In [9]: r.marker
Out[9]: <Marker('implementation_name == "cpython"')>
```

Answer (score 14):

Use https://libraries.io/. It is a good place to explore dependencies before installing using pip.

Eg. Type google-cloud-storage and search, then you can find the page for the library (https://libraries.io/rubygems/google-cloud-storage). Select the version for which you want to explore the dependencies from the 'Releases' (default is the latest), Under 'Dependencies' you can find the dependency list and their supported versions.

Comment: nice it can show the dep tree for specific versions of a package https://libraries.io/pypi/channels/2.4.0/tree

Answer (score 13):

Quite a few answers here show pip being imported for use in programs. The [documentation for pip strongly advises against this usage of pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id30).

Instead of accessing `pkg_resources` via the pip import, you can actually just import `pkg_resources` directly and use the same logic (which is actually one of the suggested solutions in the pip docs linked for anyone wanting to see package meta information programmatically) .

```
import pkg_resources

_package_name = 'yourpackagename'
  
def get_dependencies_with_semver_string():
    package = pkg_resources.working_set.by_key[_package_name]
    return [str(r) for r in package.requires()]
```

If you're having some trouble finding out exactly what your package name is, the `WorkingSet` instance returned by `pkg_resources.working_set` implements `__iter__` so you can print all of them and hopefully spot yours in there :)

i.e.

```
import pkg_resources

def print_all_in_working_set():
    ws = pkg_resources.working_set
    for package_metadata in ws:
        print(package_metadata)
```

This works with both python 2 and 3 (though you'll need to adjust the print statements for python2).

Answer (score 6):

There is the nice tool [johnnydep](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep). The benefit of it is that the package to inspect does not have to be installed.

```sh
pip install johnnydep
```

Use it like:

```sh
johnnydep deepspeech-tflite
```

Answer (score 4):

(THIS IS A LEGACY ANSWER AND SHOULD BE AVOIDED FOR MODERN PIP VERSIONS AND LEFT HERE FOR REFERENCE TO OLDER PIP VERSIONS )
Alex's answer is good (+1).   In python:

```
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.working_set.by_key['twisted'].requires()
```

should return something like

```
[Requirement.parse('zope.interface>=3.6.0')]
```

where twisted is the name of the package, which you can find in the dictionary :

```
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.WorkingSet().entry_keys
```

to list them all:

```
dict = pip._vendor.pkg_resources.WorkingSet().entry_keys
for key in dict:
    for name in dict[key]:
        req =pip._vendor.pkg_resources.working_set.by_key[name].requires()
        print('pkg {} from {} requires {}'.format(name,
                                                  key,
                                                  req))
```

should give you lists like this:

```
pkg pyobjc-framework-syncservices from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC requires [Requirement.parse('pyobjc-core>=2.5.1'), Requirement.parse('pyobjc-framework-Cocoa>=2.5.1'), Requirement.parse('pyobjc-framework-CoreData>=2.5.1')]
```

Comment: Has something changed in recent versions? The `_vendor` attribute doesn't seem to exist in pip version `19.1.1` (Edit: All right, it seems to have moved to `pkg_resources` package in the latest python version!)

Comment: Yes, things have changed, and I'm going to look at either updating this or removing it in favor of the recommendation below.

Comment: Alex's answer is only partly better from my point of view (well the `pip show` part is good, not the rest). Either use `pip show`, _pipdeptree_ or see Jordan Mackie's answer using _setuptools_' `pkg_resources` directly.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is an easy method:

`pip install --dry-run somepackage`

Comment: Note that dependencies will be downloaded are downloaded during the dry-run.

Answer (score 2):

Try this according to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) in python:

```
import pip 
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages]) 
print(installed_packages_list)
```

It will show like:

```
['behave==1.2.4', 'enum34==1.0', 'flask==0.10.1', 'itsdangerous==0.24', 
 'jinja2==2.7.2', 'jsonschema==2.3.0', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'nose==1.3.3', 
 'parse-type==0.3.4', 'parse==1.6.4', 'prettytable==0.7.2', 'requests==2.3.0',
 'six==1.6.1', 'vioozer-metadata==0.1', 'vioozer-users-server==0.1', 
 'werkzeug==0.9.4']
```

Answer (score 1):

I use johnnydep like

```
% pipx install johnnydep
% johnnydep channels==2.4.0                                                                                                                                                     
2023-01-25 16:24:25 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=channels==2.4.0 parent=None
2023-01-25 16:24:26 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=Django>=2.2 parent=channels==2.4.0
2023-01-25 16:24:27 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=asgiref~=3.2 parent=channels==2.4.0
2023-01-25 16:24:28 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=daphne~=2.3 parent=channels==2.4.0
2023-01-25 16:24:28 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 parent=Django>=2.2
2023-01-25 16:24:28 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=sqlparse>=0.2.2 parent=Django>=2.2
2023-01-25 16:24:29 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=asgiref~=3.2 parent=daphne~=2.3                          
2023-01-25 16:24:29 [info     ] init johnnydist       
...
name                                      summary
----------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
channels==2.4.0                           Brings async, event-driven capabilities to Django. Django 2.2 and up only.
├── Django>=2.2                           A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
│   ├── asgiref<4,>=3.5.2                 ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters
│   └── sqlparse>=0.2.2                   A non-validating SQL parser.
├── asgiref~=3.2                          ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters
└── daphne~=2.3                           Django ASGI (HTTP/WebSocket) server
    ├── asgiref~=3.2                      ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters
    ├── autobahn>=0.18                    WebSocket client & server library, WAMP real-time framework
    │   ├── cryptography>=3.4.6           cryptography is a package which provides cryptographic recipes and primitives to Python developers.
    │   │   └── cffi>=1.12                Foreign Function Interface for Python calling C code.
    │   │       └── pycparser             C parser in Python
    │   ├── hyperlink>=21.0.0             A featureful, immutable, and correct URL for Python.
    │   │   └── idna>=2.5                 Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
    │   ├── setuptools                    Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
    │   └── txaio>=21.2.1                 Compatibility API between asyncio/Twisted/Trollius
    └── twisted[tls]>=18.7                An asynchronous networking framework written in Python
        ├── Automat>=0.8.0                Self-service finite-state machines for the programmer on the go.
        │   ├── attrs>=19.2.0             Classes Without Boilerplate
        │   └── six                       Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
        ├── attrs>=19.2.0                 Classes Without Boilerplate
        ├── constantly>=15.1              Symbolic constants in Python
        ├── hyperlink>=17.1.1             A featureful, immutable, and correct URL for Python.
        │   └── idna>=2.5                 Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
        ├── idna>=2.4                     Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
```