# How to list dependencies for a python library without installing?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

Is there a way to get a list of dependencies for a given python package without installing it first?

I can currently get a list of requirements, but it requires installing the packages.  For example, I can use pip to show basic requirements info, but it doesn't include version information:

```
$ pip show pytest
Name: pytest
Version: 3.0.6
...
Requires: colorama, setuptools, py
```

I've tried a library called [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipdeptree/0.7.0) that includes much better output on requirements, but it also requires installation of the packages

```
$ pipdeptree -p pytest
pytest==3.0.6
- colorama [required: Any, installed: 0.3.7]
- py [required: >=1.4.29, installed: 1.4.32]
- setuptools [required: Any, installed: 34.0.0]
  - appdirs [required: >=1.4.0, installed: 1.4.0]
...
```

Ideally, I would get the level of detail that `pipdeptree` provides.  Also, being able to produce a `requirements.txt` file from a python `wheel` or from pypi with `pip` would suffice as well.

I'm interested in the dependency *constraints* for a given package, not the final downloaded packages after resolving the dependency requirements.  For example, I don't really care that pip downloaded `package-2.3.4`, I would rather know that `package>=2.1` was a requirement.

Comment: I don't know why you got that -1! Anyway, suppose you were using pip to install matplotlib. Presumably pip verifies that it has versions of the libraries that it needs to make matplotlib work successfully. Would it therefore be more likely to get you an answer if you were to ask, how does pip know which versions of requirements to install for any given library?

Comment: @BillBell An answer to that question would give me part of the solution.  Specifying requirements is somewhat fractured at the moment in python.  For wheels, I can look at the `METADATA` file and parse out the `Requires-Dist` sections.  For the legacy `tar.gz` source distributions, it's much less clear.  I'd either have to parse `requirements.txt` files, or try and parse the `setup.py` files. But `pip` and other libraries already do this, so it would be nice if I could just reuse whatever logic they are using to get the information.

Comment: I think it's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667/is-there-a-way-to-list-pip-dependencies-requirements

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PyPi provides a JSON endpoint with package metadata:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://pypi.org/pypi/{}/json'
>>> json = requests.get(url.format('pandas')).json()
>>> json['info']['requires_dist']
['numpy (>=1.9.0)', 'pytz (>=2011k)', 'python-dateutil (>=2.5.0)']
>>> json['info']['requires_python']
'>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*'
```

For a specific package version, add an additional version segment to the URL:

```
https://pypi.org/pypi/pandas/0.22.0/json
```

Comment: I downvoted because this json endpoint is not reliable.  For an example look at [`boto3`](https://pypi.org/pypi/boto3/json), the requires_dist is null but this is a project which [certainly has dependencies in the package metadata](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/setup.py#L16-L20).

Comment: @wim Maybe it was a packaging error? It works now.

Comment: @John No it doesn't work acceptably yet - they may have backfilled some more popular/important projects (like boto3) to fix them, but the bug is still there for other projects. So this info still can't be trusted, because there's no easy way to tell the difference between empty requirements and missing requirements. For example [`curl -s https://pypi.org/pypi/dulwich/json | jq ".info.requires_dist"`](https://pypi.org/pypi/dulwich/json) still shows `null` even though that project has dependencies.

Comment: @wim Yes, but these are bugs in the packages. Maybe open an issue for dulwich: There is neither an `install_requires` argument in `setup.py` nor a `setup.cfg` with `requires_dist`. Poetry also relies on these information. The method described in this answer is still good. No reason to downvote.

Comment: @John It is not a bug in the package. The package is [correctly specifying its dependencies, in pyproject.toml](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/dulwich-0.21.7/pyproject.toml#L39-L43). And if you install from the sdist with `pip install dulwich --no-binary dulwich` you will see it collect and install those dependencies too.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind installing conda, this might do the trick for you:

```
$ conda info numpy=1.11.1 python=3.6.3
```

The version numbers of the package or of python are optional (all versions will then be described)

Comment: this is deprecate. now we need to use: conda search numpy=1.11.1 --info

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `conda` gives you two options for this:

```
conda info {package}
conda install --dry-run {package}
```

I hear sometimes the latter will install the package if you provide other flags, so I would use the former.