# How can I review the dependencies for a package in PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

I noticed when I installed django using pip it installed a few additional libraries that django relied on.  Is there a way to use pip (or the Pypi website) to review those dependencies prior to installation? I can't find that anywhere. pip show  works for packages that are already installed but not remote on the index server.

Comment: You can look at `install_requires` in `setup.py` for the project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+show+dependencies+without+installing

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50424967/7976758 but read the warning in the comments.