# How can I check the dependencies needed for installation of python package?

Tags: python, package, python-packaging

I want to check dependencies needed to install in order to install the python package in linux machine (centos )  without starting the installation of package .
I want to install Pysftp package in my machine but first I wanted to know dependencies I have to install in order to install Pyftp in machine .
could someone please provide the details we can list out all the dependencies needed.

Comment: Most of the package creators include a reqiurements.txt file or include deps in setyp.py file. So you don't actually need to know the deps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a Python package's dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751572/how-to-find-a-python-packages-dependencies) OR if you want to find what OS packages you need duplicate of : https://superuser.com/questions/294662/how-to-get-list-of-dependencies-of-non-installed-rpm-package#294666

Comment: I believe this question needs to be reopened, since it's about checking dependencies of a *package that hasn't yet been installed*.

Answer (score 0):

I would install everything with anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/download). Before installing a module with `conda install ...`, it first lists all the required updates very efficiently. It is then up to the user to proceed.