# Use libcurl instead of urllib3 in pip install

Tags: python, pip, ntlm

Is there a way to get `pip install` to use `libcurl` instead of `urllib3`? I tried reading the help page of `pip install` and don’t find anything option to change to `libcurl`. The reason for asking is because `urllib3` cannot handle NTLM authentication but `libcurl` does.

My PC is behind a company firewall that uses NTLM. Solutions online points to CNTLM and Fiddler which are also blocked by company policy. This has been raised in several many github projects without any resolution and so I had to resort to finding a solution myself.

Some github issues:

1. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1182
2. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3020
3. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4967
4. https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/242
5. https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1434
6. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8047

Some SO posts:

1. [How to use pip on windows behind an authenticating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698557/how-to-use-pip-on-windows-behind-an-authenticating-proxy)
2. [Using pip behind a proxy with CNTLM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy-with-cntlm)

`pip install somepackage --proxy https://:@proxyserver:proxyport` does not work too.

Same issue with `conda`.

Comment: How are dependencies managed in your project? https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751572/how-to-find-a-python-packages-dependencies

Comment: Since pip has no options for this, You can go to your python installation on your computer and edit the pip.py file to replace `urllib` with `libcurl`.

Comment: @greenmarker thanks. the main issue is that `pip install` or `conda install` is unable to connect to the internet because of lack of the NTLM auth.

Comment: How about wget or curl the `.whl` and pip it?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen, thanks. That is the current workaround. However, it is tedious to download the dependencies and there are so many combinations (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) it can confuse the more noobs like me

Comment: Why not use CNTLM then? You've linked to 2 question discussing it.

Comment: @pynoob I know the pain. My workaround is zip all the wheels in `.cache/pip/wheels`  from my PC to gdrive (so I only need to `wget` once) and write `requirement.txt` (just `pip install -r requirement.txt` and be done with it) then hope there's no need to `apt install` anything 'cause that's blocked too.

Comment: @phd thanks. Sourceforge is also blocked.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen thanks. Thumb drive is also disabled. The IT way is probably to whitelist pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org. Or build an internal repo. But both ways are wrapped in red tape and will take ages.

Comment: Naaa, google drive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive

Comment: Then write all the wheel names in `requirement.txt` and `pip install -r requirement.txt`

Comment: All files sharing site are blocked to prevent data leakage. They even block github!