# How can I find the requirements for older TensorFlow versions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, requirements

Because right now, I am using the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20201030140623if_/https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), which is absurd.
There *must* be a better way.

**For a given TensorFlow version, e.g. 2.1, how / where can I find the related software requirements?**

More specifically, which NVIDIA GPU Drivers, Cuda Toolkit and cuDNN are required.

Answer (score 2):

One way is, you can setup a virtual environment and install tensorflow 2.1

```
$ pip install tensorflow==2.1.3
```

Then just calling the library in command line will show its dependencies

```
$ tensorflow
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751572/how-to-find-a-python-packages-dependencies) for details.

---

If you don't want to install the library,

1. You can go to the [TensorFlow releases](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases).
2. Select the specific package
3. And in the source code for the older version (will have to download its zip) in setup.py under REQUIRED_PACKAGES you can find the list.

Example here (check the path shown below to find the file)- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'absl-py ~= 0.10',
    'astunparse ~= 1.6.3',
    'flatbuffers ~= 1.12.0',
    'google_pasta ~= 0.2',
    'h5py ~= 3.1.0',
    'keras_preprocessing ~= 1.1.2',
    'numpy ~= 1.19.2',
    'opt_einsum ~= 3.3.0',
    'protobuf >= 3.9.2',
    'six ~= 1.15.0',
    'termcolor ~= 1.1.0',
    'typing_extensions ~= 3.7.4',
    'wheel ~= 0.35',
    'wrapt ~= 1.12.1',
    # These packages need to be pinned exactly as newer versions are
    # incompatible with the rest of the ecosystem
    'gast == 0.4.0',
    # TensorFlow ecosystem packages that TF exposes API for
    # These need to be in sync with the existing TF version
    # They are updated during the release process
    # When updating these, please also update the nightly versions below
    'tensorboard ~= 2.4',
    'tensorflow_estimator ~= 2.3.0',
]
```

Comment: That's almost what I am looking, but I still need to know the required GPU drivers, toolkit, etc.

Comment: This would be a direct link but I am not sure if this is what you are looking for https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#older_versions_of_tensorflow