# How to check version dependencies of python packages

Tags: python, pip, package

I am using a python application which requires me to install the `python requests version 2.23.0` and above.
Currently `requests` package is installed in my system with a version of `2.22.0`.

And requests is a package that is extensively used by many of my script and other packages also has dependency on `requests` library.

Is there a way I can ensure that upgrade of this library will not cause any issues to other libraries that might have dependency on `requests` library?

Answer (score 1):

If you use virtual  environments like venv ([Python venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)), you will be able to install different versions of any package at the same time. You just have to create an environment only for the scripts that require the higher version. Also requests in general isn't that much of a problem when it comes to upgrading most of the time. Most updates provide full backwards compatibility.

EDIT: If you just want to get the dependency tree for a pip package, use pipdeptree ([quote from according Stackoverflow-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751572/how-to-find-a-python-packages-dependencies#39488113))