# How can I determine if I need to install psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2, python-c-api

I am trying to build a generic tool to bootstrap an EMR cluster. Some of the jobs we run in PySpark on EMR require psycopg2. Others don't. For the ones that require psycopg2, we need to `yum install postgresql-devel`. Otherwise, we don't. So I'm trying to detect if psycopg2 is a dependency.

However, every approach I've tried so far (using pip-23.0.1) results in this output [from PostgresConfig](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/0b01ded426b7423621af68d9fc33e532a5bda4a7/setup.py#L81) when psycopg2 is a dependency:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /mnt/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-qjiuibm3/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /mnt/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-qjiuibm3/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /mnt/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-qjiuibm3/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /mnt/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-qjiuibm3/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/mnt/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-qjiuibm3/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

This includes ideas from these posts including `pip-compile`, `pip download` and `pip install --dry-run`.

1. [How to find a Python package's dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751572)
2. [Is there a way to list pip dependencies/requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667)

Here are a few ways to reproduce the behavior I'm seeing. (Assume that `requirements.in` contains the name of the package we're trying to install. In the simplest case, it can just contain "psycopg2".)

```
pip-compile requirements.in --output-file requirements.txt
# or
pip download --dest /tmp --requirement requirements.in
# or
pip install --dry-run --requirement requirements.in |
    sed -n 's/^Would install //p' |
    tr ' ' '\n' |
    sed 's/\(.*\)-/\1==/g' > requirements.txt
```

(Following the above, I intended to either grep the resolved `requirements.txt`, or search the download dir for psycopg2. But I don't get that far.)

As a last-ditch, I could try doing `pip install --dry-run`, capture the stderr and parse it for the above message, but is there a more elegant way to tell if `psycopg2` is a dependency (transitive or direct) *without* triggering `PostgresConfig`?

A general solution for determining if a c extension would need to be compiled would also be helpful, if you know of one.

Comment: *approach I've tried so far* - how did it look (in code)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have edited the question to include the iterations I've tried.