# How to find where a package is used in Python?

Tags: python, security, dependencies, package

I'm writing program for commercial use and the company vulnerability scan gave me this.

[image]

Clicking on the links leads me to here https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-15560. Now I'm sure I've never explicitly used any of these packages, I don't even know what they do.

I ran `pip show pycrypto`, `pip show pycryptodome` inside the docker container running the program, but got this:

```
root@ism-core-es-deployment-dev-6d94bc549-959bt:/app# python3 -m pip show pycryptodome
WARNING: Package(s) not found: pycryptodome
root@ism-core-es-deployment-dev-6d94bc549-959bt:/app# pip show pycrypto
WARNING: Package(s) not found: pycrypto
```

And they're not importable in python for me to dig more information. So my question is: how do you find which library/which part of my code is running this? I only know pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz is the package in question.

Comment: Shouldn't the scanner tell you where it found the files?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm also trying to wrap my head around why it doesn't do that. Maybe I'm just not looking hard enough. But I think I should solve that first before digging python functionalities.Thank you.

Comment: see my answer to [reverse dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353494) .  Might be helpful in your case.  basically, find out where your site_package directory, then use a specialized grep search to find who is using what.  how Docker affects that?  not sure.