# Python package usage (reverse dependencies extended to not installed ones)

Tags: python, dependencies

Is there an easy way to determine for a Python package, by which other—not installed—packages it is used?

For instance when I found an interesting package and want to know whether another project *using* it might save me from reinventing the wheel, for what I *actually* want to implement.
So like `pipdeptree --reverse` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336323/show-reverse-dependencies-with-pip/61173669?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C0.0000#61173669)) extended to packages that I do not have installed, but are known on github.com or pypi.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incidentially saw on github the **Used by** link (right sidebar), which is a short-cut to https://github.com/.../network/dependents/ (also via **Insights**).